# Is there a way to use native input interfaces in a PWA?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Each operating system has its own standardized input interfaces -- for example, on iOS any dropdown typically looks something like this:

[image: iOS dropdown]

Is there a way to tap into this UI from a PWA, or is this for native apps only?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard html select. When safari takes over on iOS it should automatically use the native UI for selection. You cannot modify it however.